# Set content_type of Fog storage files on s3

Tags: amazon-s3, content-type, ruby-on-rails-4, fog

I'm working with Fog and Amazon s3 to manage video and image files. I've been running into a lot of trouble with setting the content_type for my files.

When working from the console, I am able to go through and individually update each file's content_type, and then run save. However, when I try to run an update on all of the files within a specific directory, I don't get an error, but nothing gets updated. I've run multiple different methods, all with the same basic idea, and all set to print "saved!" if the file saves. The methods run properly and print out "saved!", but when I go back and check the files, the content_type is still nil.

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
directory.files.each do |f|
  case f.key.split(".").last
  when "jpg"
    f.content_type = "image/jpeg"
    puts "saved!" if f.save
  when "mov"
    f.content_type = "video/quicktime"
    puts "saved!" if f.save
  end
end
```

Also, when I go through and individually update each file, the save works and the content_type gets updated, but the data doesn't persist.

For example:

```
file = directory.files.first
file.content_type = 'video/quicktime'
file.save         # returns true
file.content_type # returns 'video/quicktime'
```

However, when I go check the file in AWS, the content type is still nil.

Is there a better (persistent) way of going about updating content_type on Fog s3 files? I feel like I must be going about this the wrong way.

Update:
Tried using the file#copy method:

```
directory.files.each do |f|
  content_type = case f.key.split(".").last
  when "jpg"
    "image/jpeg"
  when "mov"
    "video/quicktime"
  end
  puts "copied!" if f.copy(f.directory.key, f.key, { 'Content-Type' => content_type })
end
```

I got an error:

```
Excon::Errors::BadRequest: Expected(200) <=> Actual(400 Bad Request)

from /Users/marybethlee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@mothership/gems/excon-0.22.1/lib/excon/middlewares/expects.rb:6:in `response_call'
from /Users/marybethlee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@mothership/gems/excon-0.22.1/lib/excon/connection.rb:355:in `response'
from /Users/marybethlee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@mothership/gems/excon-0.22.1/lib/excon/connection.rb:249:in `request'
from /Users/marybethlee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@mothership/gems/fog-1.11.1/lib/fog/core/connection.rb:21:in `request'
from /Users/marybethlee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@mothership/gems/fog-1.11.1/lib/fog/aws/storage.rb:506:in `request'
from /Users/marybethlee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@mothership/gems/fog-1.11.1/lib/fog/aws/requests/storage/copy_object.rb:33:in `copy_object'
from /Users/marybethlee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@mothership/gems/fog-1.11.1/lib/fog/aws/models/storage/file.rb:93:in `copy'
from (irb):14
from /Users/marybethlee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are just updating metadata (and not the body/content itself) you probably want to use copy instead of save. This is perhaps non-obvious, but that keeps the operation on the S3 side so that it will be MUCH faster.

The signature for copy looks like:

`copy(target_directory_key, target_file_key, options = {})`

So I think my proposed solution should look (more or less) like this:

```
directory.files.each do |f|
  content_type = case f.key.split(".").last
  when "jpg"
    "image/jpeg"
  when "mov"
    "video/quicktime"
  end
  options = {
    'Content-Type' => content_type,
    'x-amz-metadata-directive' => 'REPLACE'
  }
  puts "copied!" if f.copy(f.directory, f.key, options)
end
```

That should basically tell S3 "copy my file over the top of itself, but change this header". That way you don't have to download/reupload the file. This is probably the approach you want.

So, solution aside, still seems like you found a bug. Could you include an example of what you mean by "individually update each file"? Just want to make sure I know exactly what you mean and that I can see the working/non-working cases side by side. Also, how/why do you think it isn't updating the content-type (it might actually be updating it, but just not displaying the updated value correctly, or something like that). Bonus points if you can create an issue here to make sure I don't forget to address it: https://github.com/fog/fog/issues?state=open

Comment: So I tried what you suggested, but got an error:
`Excon::Errors::BadRequest: Expected(200) <=> Actual(400 Bad Request)`
I'll edit my original post to include the error, as well as examples of what I meant by the individual update

Comment: Thanks for the update. I found at least one issue (I had overlooked that you need to specify 'REPLACE', since by default it will use the old metadata and disregard anything passed in the copy request).

In addition, a bit more detail of the error would be handy. Could you update your fog version and try again? I don't know that it will fix it, but it should at least give a bit more detailed error message. Thanks!

Comment: Aha! yep specifying replace fixed the error, but it's still the same problem I was running into before. Going through the loop prints out copied, but the content type is still nil for all of the files, and individually updating them seems like it's working, but doesn't make it up to aws

Comment: To clarify then. You make the request and it appears to succeed, how are you looking up the content type that is returning a nil? Are you doing `files.all.each {|file| file.content_type}` or `files.get(key).content_type` or something else? Just want to make sure I know whats up on that end (as it may be being set on S3 but just not updating/showing correctly on the client side). In particular I don't think this info is included by default when doing `files.all`.

Comment: You're right. If I do `directory.files.first.content_type`, I get nil. But if I pass that same file's key into `directory.files.get(key).content_type`, it returns `"video/quicktime`. Is that an S3 related issue, or is it even an issue? I can work with it now that I know what's going on.

Comment: It's an S3 related limitation/issue, yeah. The API calls you use to get a single file (vs get a list of files) return slightly different results, as you probably well know. Unfortunately the list of files version doesn't include much metadata (you can see more completely what it does include here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html). So that info just isn't accessible there.

Comment: Oops, enter = submit, not newline! All that said, you could also force the info to be loaded by doing `directory.files.first.reload.content_type`, which will do that get for you. Note that this means a lot of API calls though. Ultimately I think either the method you were using or the copy method we figured out SHOULD be setting the content-type as expected (unfortunately it just doesn't reveal that inside the list of files). Hope that clarifies everything, but definitely let me know if I can help with anything else. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that information! The copy method worked for setting the content_type, I just had to be a bit roundabout in finding it again. It's good to know that this is an issue, so that I don't get caught up with it again. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: No worries, I definitely understand how confusing/surprising that likely is. Unfortunately, not much we can do better (without doing a `head` to every object or something, which isn't a great general solution as you might have thousands of objects). Anyway, glad that got you what you needed!

Comment: Update 7 years later: with the version of Fog I'm using, I had to use `f.directory.key` instead of just `f.directory` so it was `f.copy(f.directory.key, f.key, options)`

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround to get the content type:

`directory.files.head(file.key).content_type`

where `file.key` is the name of your file.